# How to test that a Redux dispatch function gets called during componentDidMount in React class component?

Tags: reactjs, testing, redux, jestjs, react-testing-library

Here is my basic React setup:

1. I have a React class Component
2. That is connected to my Redux store using connect()
3. That fires a function during componentDidMount
4. and that function is one that the Component has access to via mapDispatchToProps (implicitly)

I want to test that the above more or less works, that a specific function, in this cases `fetchComments` gets called during the `componentDidMount` lifecycle even of my component.

Here is the relevant component code:

```
class CommentContainer extends React.Component{
  componentDidMount(){
    this.props.fetchComments(this.props.resourceId)
  }

...

export default connect(mapStateToProps, { authorizeUser, addComment, fetchComments })(CommentContainer)
```

For testing, I have tried A LOT of different approaches. The only thing I can get to work is not to test that `fetchComments` has been called (which from my understanding would be the best way to isolate functionality), but to test that the store gets updated in a specific way (which would only happen if `fetchComments` gets called).

The test I have that works:

```
import { render } from '@testing-library/react'

...

it ('loads comments upon rendering', ()=> {
  const store = createStore(rootReducer, applyMiddleware(thunk)) //I've also tried mockStores, but that didn't seem to work well with the connect() method in the component
  expect(store.getState().comments.loadStatus).toBe(null)
  render(<Provider store={store}>
          <Router>
              <CommentContainer 
                relativePath={"/resources/:id"} 
                resourceId={1}
              />
            </Router>
          </Provider>
        )
  expect(store.getState().comments.loadStatus).not.toBe(null)
}
```

What I would like to do is something more along the lines of:

```
const spy = jest.spyOn(store, "dispatch")
render(<Provider store={store}>
            <Router>
            <CommentContainer 
              relativePath={"/resources/:id"} 
              resourceId={1}
            />
          </Router>
        </Provider>
        )
expect(spy).toHaveBeenCalledWith(fetchComments)
```

However, when I do this the test fails. The spy gets called twice, and the output I get is:

```
Expected: [Function fetchComments]
    Received
           1: [Function anonymous]
           2: [Function anonymous]
```

I gather this is happening because under the hood, `store.dispatch` is getting passed an anonymous function with the "work" of `fetchComments` but not getting passed the actual function `fetchComments`. Is that accurate?

I have also tried, among other things, creating a mock function of `fetchComments` and passing that as a prop directly to `CommentContainer`, but that prop seems to get overwritten by the `connect()` method and `mapDispatchToProps`

Another thing I tried was to use Enzyme and `shallow` and `mount` instead of react-testing-library's `render` and then use the `.props()` method to retrieve `fetchComments` from `CommentContainer`, but when I did that I got an error that prop was "Read Only" so I couldn't do something like `jest.spyOn(wrapper.props, 'fetchComments')`

I'd appreciate any feedback on how to make this work or how I should test this functionality.